# How to obtain unescaped string value of Newtonsoft.Json deserialized value?

Tags: json, escaping, json.net, json-deserialization

I am trying to parse some JSON objects which is made just of (string,string) pairs. The file I am parsing contains this. I want ot emulate resjson behaviour.

```
{
  "first_key": "first_value",
  "unicode": "\u0040 @"
}
```

What I do is

```
string path = @"d:\resjson\example.resjson";
string jsonText = File.ReadAllText(path);

IDictionary<string, string> dict;
try
{
    dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, string>>(jsonText);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  // log or something
}
```

When I obtain the dict object, the

```
foreach (var pair in _dict)
{
  string key = pair.Key;
  string value = pair.Value;

  Console.WriteLine("Key = '{0}', Value = '{1}'", key, value);
}
```

This inputs for me :

```
"Key = 'first_key', Value = 'first_value'"
"Key = 'unicode', Value = '@ @'"
```

Once Newtonsoft.Json deserializes the object, I lose the "\u0040" string and I have no way of knowing how the original file looked like. Is there a way to preserve character escaping ?

Comment: If you initialize a string with value "\u0040 @" and retrieve it again it will show the value as "@ @".

Comment: @SergiuMindras Why do you need this?

Comment: @Athari I want to obtain the 'true' value of the original string because I want to underline it based on LineInfo. For that i need where the string starts and where it ends, but LineInfo returns only LinePosition and LineNumber (line and column).

Comment: @Manvik but when you read from a file it should read as "\\u0040 @". It is not initializing a string as "\u0040 @" which will interpret "\u0040" as a single character.
File.ReadAllText(path) reads the characters as they are.

Comment: if I open notepad and write "\u0040 @" i want the program to know that it has to underline 8 characters, not 3

Answer (score 0):

Well, one simple idea would be to escape all the backslashes in the original text before passing it to the parser:

```
dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, string>>(
           jsonText.Replace(@"\", @"\\"));
```

Comment: the problem is that this way I might mess up other values, though it works on this particular case. 
I might have some other values there "\b somestring", "\f otherstring" etc.

Comment: And how would those values be messed up?  Are you saying that you only want the escaping preserved for `\u`?  If so, just change the Replace statement to look for that `(@"\u", @"\\u")`.

Comment: (@"\u", @"\\u") messes up the case when i have the string "\\u0040". 
It will turn into "\\\u0040" which will be parsed as "\@"

Answer (score 0):

Using Newtonsoft.Json, you can actually do:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject([obj or JToken], settings);
```

It won't show the original string as that is lost when deserializing, but it will encode all non ascii characters as \uXXXX